# RegEx to find and extract full sentences containing a certain word or symbol?

Tags: regex

Using regex, I'm trying to find and extract all full sentences that mention "100%" (honestly, any mention of the % symbol would work too).

My problem is that I'm working off of HTML. So I used =REGEXREPLACE to replace all the HTML code with empty spaces. It's definitely not clean at all. From here, is there a regex that could maybe just grab the first five words before "100%" and the first five words after "100%"? I technically don't need the full sentence, just enough context for the 100%.

I've tried:

```
(?:\S+\s)?\S*100%\S*(?:\s\S+)?
```

But it doesn't get the word before colons or semicolons. (Sometimes sentences are formed as "Benefits: 100% coverage of fees." Below is an example I'm working with, but I have must larger blocks of text I need to sift through..

```html
 Benefits Full coverage    100% coverage of fees  (e.g., registration fees) for every program available in the   program catalog
```

Ideally, it'd be great if I could get just "Full coverage 100% coverage of fees"

Comment: What's wrong with literally `100%`?, or if you're trying to match the whole line `^.*100%.*$`?

Comment: Regex is unreliable to parse HTML, better to traverse the DOM. Also what is the expected output based on your example?

Comment: Hopefully to make this easier, I used =REGEXREPLACE to replace all the HTML code with empty spaces. I've edited my snippet to reflect that. It's definitely not clean at all. From here, is there a regex that could maybe just grab the first five words before "100%" and the first five words after "100%"? I technically don't need the full sentence, just enough context for the 100%.

Comment: Please include a snippet of your expected output.